# Gradle with GWT2.8, error: Execution failed for task ':compileGwt'

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, gwt

Trying to compile my GWT code using Gradle using the link: 
Changes incorporated in the `build.gradle` file to work for gwt.

```
    apply plugin: 'gwt'

    gwt {
        gwtVersion='2.8.0'
        modules 'com.idc.facade.IdcFacade'

        maxHeapSize = "1024M"

        superDev {
        noPrecompile=true
        }

    }
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            maven {
                url 'http://artifactory.wellsfargo.com/artifactory/idc_maven_deploy_virtual'
                credentials {
                    username = "${artifactory_user}"
                    password = "${artifactory_password}"
                }
            }


    }
    dependencies {
        //Check for the latest version here: http://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.jfrog.artifactory
        classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:4+"
        classpath 'de.richsource.gradle.plugins:gwt-gradle-plugin:0.6'

    }
}
allprojects {
    apply plugin: "com.jfrog.artifactory"
}

artifactory {
    contextUrl = "${artifactory_contextUrl}"   //The base Artifactory URL if not overridden by the publisher/resolver
    publish {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'idc_maven_deploy_snapshot_local'
            username = "${artifactory_user}"
            password = "${artifactory_password}"
            maven = true

        }
    }
    resolve {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'idc_maven_deploy_virtual'
            username = "${artifactory_user}"
            password = "${artifactory_password}"
            maven = true

        }
    }
}
```

When I try to do Gradle>build in the Gradle Tasks tab in eclipse, I get the below error:

```
WARNING: Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs at root 0x80000002. Windows RegCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code 5.
Loading inherited module 'com.idc.facade.IdcFacade'
   [ERROR] Failure while parsing XML
org.xml.sax.SAXNotRecognizedException: Feature: http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl.setFeature(SAXParserFactoryImpl.java:100)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser.createNewSaxParser(ReflectiveParser.java:61)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser.access$000(ReflectiveParser.java:48)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:345)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.access$200(ReflectiveParser.java:70)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:431)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.nestedLoad(ModuleDefLoader.java:316)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.load(ModuleDefLoader.java:243)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.doLoadModule(ModuleDefLoader.java:193)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.loadFromResources(ModuleDefLoader.java:151)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.loadFromClassPath(ModuleDefLoader.java:126)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:139)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler$1.run(Compiler.java:118)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.doRun(CompileTaskRunner.java:55)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.runWithAppropriateLogger(CompileTaskRunner.java:50)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.main(Compiler.java:125)
:compileGwt FAILED
:compileGwt (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 22,5,main]) completed. Took 1.403 secs.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileGwt'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':compileGwt'.
```

Comment: This looks like a compile time error, not related to Gradle. Looks like there is something wrong in the file IdcFacade.gwt.xml.

Comment: Hi, I got rid of this error by including the the depend xercesImpl.jar